# Why can't ionization chamber give us energy spectrum?

Tags: particle-detectors, gamma-rays

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionization_chamber):

*However, the chamber cannot discriminate between radiation types (beta or gamma) and cannot produce an energy spectrum of radiation.*

Why is this? I would suppose, that a gamma photon with higher energy will produce more ion pairs and thus more current.

How is the ionization chamber different from the proportional chamber? To me it seems they basically give the same output, but in proportional chamber it's amplified by the avalanches - so we just have a stronger signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ionization chamber output is a small current, equal to the charges
released by ionizing radiation.   The current is no different if
the incident photons are 200 eV each, and 30,000 per second
or if they are 30 eV each, and 200,000 per second.   Those
two cases are indistinguishable to an ionization chamber.

A proportional counter is a pulse generator, making pulses
with 'height' according to the energy of the detected particle,
and as many pulses per second as particles incident on the detector
during that second.   So, 200 eV photons generate big pulses,
and 30,000 big pulses per second tells you both the energy per particle
and the number of particles.   It tells you the spectrum.